# Camera and picture selection crashes sometimes

Tags: android

I inserted on my application a section to take and select pictures, but unfortunately, sometimes, when I take a photo or I select a picture to save on my server, the application crashes. Is really weird because my application only crashes sometimes.

I'm receiving this error:

```
ViewRootImpl #2 Surface is not valid.
```

How can I check if the photo is null and prevent my application from crashing?

My code:

```
private void selectImage() {

    final CharSequence[] options = {"Take photo","My gallery","Cancel" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PhotosActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Adicionar foto!");
    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (options[item].equals("My gallery"))
            {
                Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

            }
            else if (options[item].equals("Take photo")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
            else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       if (requestCode == 1) {
           File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
           for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
               if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                   f = temp;
                   break;
               }
           } 
           try {
               Bitmap bitmap;
               BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

               bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                       bitmapOptions); 

               if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
                   Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                   matrix.postRotate(getExifOrientation(f.getAbsolutePath()));
                   bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap , 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
               }

               int nh = (int) ( bitmap.getHeight() * (612.0 / bitmap.getWidth()) );
               Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 612, nh, true);

               ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
               scaled.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream);

               byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
               String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);

               newtask = new saveImage();
               newtask.execute(image_str,sessionid);

               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "A sua imagem estará brevemente disponível.",
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               String path = android.os.Environment
                       .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                       + File.separator
                       + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
               f.delete();




               FileOutputStream outFile = null;
               File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
               try {
                   outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                   outFile.flush();
                   outFile.close();
               } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

       if (requestCode == 2) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();


            String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);


            c.close();
            Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

            if (thumbnail.getWidth() > thumbnail.getHeight()) {
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(getExifOrientation(picturePath));
                thumbnail = Bitmap.createBitmap(thumbnail , 0, 0, thumbnail.getWidth(), thumbnail.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            }

            int nh = (int) ( thumbnail.getHeight() * (612.0 / thumbnail.getWidth()) );
            Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(thumbnail, 612, nh, true);

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            scaled.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream);

            byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
            String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);

            if (image_str != null) {
            newtask = new saveImage();
            newtask.execute(image_str,sessionid);
            }


            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "A sua imagem estará brevemente disponível.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
}  

public static int getExifOrientation(String filepath) {
    int degree = 0;
    ExifInterface exif = null;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(filepath);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (exif != null) {
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, -1);
        if (orientation != -1) {
            switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                degree = 90;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                degree = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                degree = 270;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    return degree;
}
```

Logcat

> 06-21 15:42:42.890: E/HAWAII_EGL(1795): Destroying surface without
>   window
>
> 06-21 15:42:49.376: I/dalvikvm(2183): Could not find method
>   android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced
>   from method
>   android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
>
> 06-21 15:42:49.376: I/dalvikvm(2183): Could not find method
>   android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType

Comment: show logcat error....

Comment: When crashes, my Logcat shows this error:  Destroying surface without window... But only when it crashes, when it works my logcat doesn't show any error.